List of pesukim you can add to Musaf of Rosh Hashanah?
In Rosh Hashana musaf, we are required to say 10 pesukim each for malchuyos, zichronos, and shofaros.  You are allowed to say more than 10, and the standard minhag in machzorim that I've seen is to say a couple more.
In case you'd want to add even more, has anyone compiled a list of all candidate pesukim in Tanach that can work, following all the halachic criteria (not פורעניות, not זכרון של יחיד, etc.)?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114589/759

I doubt anyone has compiled all of them but it should be reasonable to collect all those that have been used in various historical piyyutim and/or mentioned by rishonim as options. Outside those you're bound to end up with ambiguities sometimes
